# How do I automatically backup db.sqlite3 file in Django App hosted on Azure Web Apps?

Tags: python, django, azure

I have a Django web application hosted on _________.azurewebsites.net

The folder structure is as follows:

```
- Github Repository
     - settingsFolder
     - app1folder
     - app2folder
     - manage.py 
     - web.config
     - db.sqlite3
```

I have Azure set up to where a push to my remote github branch causes Azure to sync the files with my Github branch to my /site/wwwroot/ folder.

Explicitly,

```
git push origin branch
```

This causes a problem.  Everytime I try to add changes to my website, using git push, the db.sqlite3 DOES NOT reflect the changes within the website environment.  Thus, if someone were to save data to /site/wwwroot/db.sqlite3, then my github repository would be UNAWARE of the changes.  Updating my github repository would take the OLD db.sqlite3 and reupload THIS OLD during a file sync between Azure and github. Consequently, the db.sqlite3 on /site/wwwroot/ gets overwritten and data would be lost.

One solution is to manually make backups by connecting to my /site/wwwroot folder, saving db.sqlite3, and replacing it regularly in my Github repository.

Is it possible to automate this? If so, what resources does Azure provide me to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is wrong in quite a few ways.

Firstly, your sqlite file should not be in version control. Your local db is just that, local; it shouldn't be deployed to production, for exactly the reason you're experiencing. Delete it from git and ensure it is in your `.gitignore` file.

Secondly, it's not really appropriate to use a file-based db in production. Sqlite is a great tool but as soon as you move to a real production site you need a real database. Apart from anything else, if you find you need to scale your site to more than one Azure instance, they will each have a separate copy of the database file, so data will quickly get out of sync. Use a real db like PostgreSQL; yet another benefit of that is that your host will take care of backing it up.

Comment: Thank you.  I will do the .gitignore. 

There are several reasons why I took this route.  I don't expect this to scale. I'm not selling a product and I'm still learning. I needed to create a usable prototype ASAP.

I will keep PostgreSQL in mind when I do choose to scale.  For now, I have to "hack" a solution for a quick fix.  Bad practice I know.  I'll learn better practice when I need to.

Say I choose to do PostgreSQL.  Is this possible with the Microsoft Imagine Subscription?

Comment: As I finished writing that, I need a quick solution to what I have.  I want to stick with SQLite.  How will I be able to fix this solution and keep my SQLite file?

Comment: You'll need to take a copy of your remote file, then locally do `git rm --cached db.sqlite3` and add "db.sqlite3" to .gitignore, commit the result and push, then restore the original remote. Subsequent pushes will leave the file untouched.

Comment: If I need to change the database schema (add, delete or change a model) how will I make sure the changes work in deployment while maintaining all the changes that happened before deployment?




So In my mind, right before deploying, I'd copy the db.sqlite3 file from site/wwwroot/db.sqlite3, paste it in my local/db.sqlite3, makemigrations, migrate, and deploy, with git. Then redeploy with .gitignore



Did you have another solution in mind?

Comment: That is what migrations are for.

Comment: Hi, sorry I tried to  enter/return and accidently added comment too early. Please see my question with added details. 

Also, how do I show carriage returns or new lines here?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. This copy/gitignore thing only needs to be done once, to take the file out of version control. Once that's done any further deploys just happen normally, they won't disturb the file that's there. So you can run migrations after deploying as normal.

Comment: If I made a change to my model in Django, I would have to perform migrations.  I assume (and I may be wrong) that running migrations changes my db.sqlite3 file because changes to the model changes the schema of the database.  Because I changed db.sqlite3, gitignore won't reflect that change in schema and thus my web app won't work properly.  I suggested a way around this and was hoping it was a workable approach.